# Не могу запустить Eclipse, выдаёт ошибку

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

Не запускается Eclipse, только что установил. Подскажите: что может быть ?

Вот лог, который лежит по адресу

```html
!SESSION 2018-02-27 17:22:18.345 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.I20130605-2000
java.version=9.0.4
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ru_RU
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-27 17:22:19.721
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:233)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:656)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:275)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
 ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The System Bundle could not be resolved: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.checkSystemState(BaseStorage.java:827)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:800)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getState(BaseAdaptor.java:387)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.frameworkStart(BaseStorage.java:923)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:250)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:60)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
 at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
 ... 13 more
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста файл лога, который лежит по указанному в сообщению адресу.

Answer (score 1):

Вы устанавливает Эклипс, который работает на Java5, а у Вас установлена Java9. Или установите свежий Эклипс или поставьте древнюю JRE